# Comparative or superlative with plural

Tags: comparative

Let's sat I have a set of 10 different positive numbers. I want to pick the 4 with the smaller (*or smallest?*) value. Should I say "*the four smaller values*" or "*the four smallest values*"?

In other words, which of the following is correct?

> 1, 2, 3, 4 are the smaller positive natural numbers
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4 are the smallest positive natural numbers

Answer (score 1):

Smaller is used when you are comparing.

in a list like: 5, 8, 20, 15, 7, 2

15 is smaller than 20

The smallest number is 2

The four smallest numbers in this list are: 2, 5, 7 and 8.

So your answer would be:

> 1, 2, 3, 4 are the smallest positive natural numbers.

Comment: The answer "would be" or it is? (Also I edited your question to get rid of the `mark up text`.

Comment: @Cássio Salles, thank you for the answer. By picking up four numbers I am implicitly doing a comparison among all the numbers. Therefore, I am not still certain that the comparative form is "wrong". By instinct I could say "the four smaller numbers", but I am not a native speaker. Therefore, I leave the question open to more answers.